# Is MVVM an alternative to Expression Blend?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, expression-blend

I'm sure this is a Noob question, but I've never worked with WPF before. Is MVVM an alternative to Expression Blend?

Comment: Not sure why you were voted down. +1 for your newfound knowledge.

Comment: Thanks for all your answers. They all helped me better understand.

Comment: Brave of you to ask such a question in this shark-infested environment we call SO.  8)  upvote!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No.  They are completely different concepts.

Expression Blend is software for creating interfaces - it's a designer's tool for working with WPF.

MVVM is a design pattern - it's an architecture you can use to make your WPF application clean and easily maintainable.

You are perfectly capable of using Blend together with MVVM - in fact, this is one of the benefits MVVM provides (it makes it very easy to keep the UI design separate from the programming).

Comment: Thanks Reed. I did look at the Wiki for it, but as a beginner a lot of the information was over my head. Thanks for being succinct

Comment: Should be clear that Expression Blend is used for creating the look and feel aspects of your apps - the view (where the buttons, controls are, what color, how they are represented) - but not the code.

Answer (score 4):

No; MVVM is a design pattern while Expression Blend is a program. See:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MVVM
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expression_Blend
http://www.google.com/

Blend actually creates code that can be used as MVVM

Answer (score 4):

No, not at all.  In fact, MVVM is supposed to be a way to help a designer using Expression Blend work with the developer writing the functionality.  The idea is that MVVM provides better separation between the View and the ViewModel.  This gives you some advantages:

- You can replace the real ViewModel with a mock ViewModel (XML based, perhaps) which allows the designer to have some data to play with inside of Blend.
- You can write unit tests for your ViewModel which (hopefully) includes all your functionality.  The unit test becomes another consumer of your ViewModel, just as the View is.

Comment: +1 for pointing out that 'Blendability' is often one of the goals of MVVM (e.g. in Laurent's MVVM Light)